# How to check if user uploads the same file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My case: user have to upload xls file with some data (warehouse leftovers) from 1C.
Script checks if this data contains any mistakes and show them to user.
After that user have to fix these mistakes in warehouse database and get from it new file to upload.
But nothing can stop user from fix mistakes right in xls file instead of database.
I thouth that script will compare time of creation of files, but JS have no access to file system, so I can't get time of creation, just last modified data.
Is there any other way to check if user uploads new file instead of fixed old one?

Answer (score 1):

Hash the file content to know if they are the same

You can use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha.js/v/2.4.9, but you can go for any hash function you want

```
const fileContent1 = "My file";
const fileContent2 = "My file";
const hash1 = shajs("sha256").update(fileContent1).digest("hex");
const hash2 = shajs("sha256").update(fileContent2).digest("hex");
```

And then you just compare the hashes to see if the files are the same, and handle your logic, I can change the example if you need more context, but I would need more info about how your code is getting the file for upload, and if it reads it for something

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mirzakhani-muii3?file=/src/index.js